# php - Copy value from array into another array in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that contains multiple transactions, with multiple transactions being from the same email address.

Some of these transactions have a value in the `client` key. Others don't.

I want to copy the filled `client` key in all matching arrays with the same `email_address` key, in order to always have data in the `client` key.

Example of my array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [client] => John John
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [client] => Kevin Kevin
            [email_address] => kevin@kevin.com
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [client] => 
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )

)
```

What I want to achieve is to make sure that `Array [5]` has the same value in the `client` key as `Array [1]` because it's the same client (based on `email_address` key).

Example of the resulted array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [client] => John John
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [client] => Kevin Kevin
            [email_address] => kevin@kevin.com
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [client] => John John
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )

)
```

How can I go through the array to make sure that matching arrays (based on `email_address` key) always have the same `client` key?

Comment: How much `client` you want to fill...

Comment: @RivnatNasah All, whatever data a filled `client` key contains. So, `John John` from `Array [1]` to be `John John` in `Array [5]`

Comment: So what's your question? "I want to do X" or "Write me code that does X" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `array_column`, `array_unique`, `array_flip`, `array_count_values`, `array_filter` and `array_intersect_key` functions (This solution is also well-suited for processing multiple groups of "client" entries with same "email_address"):

```
// supposing $arr is your initial array

$ties = array_flip(array_unique(array_column($arr, "email_address", "client")));
$counts = array_filter(array_count_values(array_column($arr, "email_address")), function($v){
    return $v > 1;  // getting number of entries with same 'email' attribute
});    
$relations = array_intersect_key($ties, $counts);   // contains pairs of relative email/client entries, like "[john@john.com] => John John"

foreach ($arr as &$client) {
    if (!$client['client'] && key_exists($client['email_address'], $relations)) {
        $client['client'] = $relations[$client['email_address']];
    }
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [client] => John John
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [client] => Kevin Kevin
            [email_address] => kevin@kevin.com
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [client] => John John
            [email_address] => john@john.com
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an intermediate array that relates email addresses to client. Like this:

```
$intermediateArray = [];

foreach ($inputArray as $row) {
  if (isset($row['client']) {
    $intermediateArray[$row['email_address']] = $row['client']
  }
}
```

and then fill in the missing client cells:

```
foreach ($inputArray as $row) {
  if (!isset($row['client']) {
    if (isset($intermediateArray[$row['email_address']])) {
      $row['client'] = $intermediateArray[$row['email_address']];
    }   
  }
}
```

More efficient solutions are possible, but this one seems the simplest.